# parsing large dataset with python

Tags: python, parsing

I have a large matrix in a gzip that looks something like this:

```
locus_1 mark1 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.4536,0.8177,0.4929,0.0,0.0
locus_2 mark2 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.5536,0.9177,0.2929,0.0,0.0
locus_3 mark2 0.0,0.0,0.1,0.0,0.0,0.9536,0.8177,0.2827,0.0,0.0
```

So, each row starts with two descriptors, followed by 10 values.

I simply want to parse out the first 5 values of this row, such that I have a matrix like this:

```
locus_1 mark1 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
locus_2 mark2 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
locus_3 mark2 0.0,0.0,0.1,0.0,0.0
```

I have made the following python script to parse this, but to no avail:

```
import gzip
import numpy as np

inFile = gzip.open('/home/anish/data.gz')

inFile.next()

for line in inFile:
        cols = line.strip().replace('nan','0').split('\t')
        data = cols[2:]
        data = map(float,data)

        gfpVals =  data[:5]

        print '\t'.join(cols[:6]) + '\t' + '\t'.join(map(str,gfpVals))
```

I simply get the error:

```
data = map(float,data)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: apologies- that not the error. the error is:  data = map(float,data)
ValueError: invalid literal for float():

Comment: If you thought my response answered your question I would appreciate it if you accepted it as the answer, so that this question does not keep appearing as unanswered.

Comment: [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using only tabs as delimiters while the values are delimited also by commas.

As a result

```
locus_1 mark1 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.4536,0.8177,0.4929,0.0,0.0
```

is split to

```
locus_1 || mark1 || 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.4536,0.8177,0.4929,0.0,0.0
```

and you are passing to float the string

```
"0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.4536,0.8177,0.4929,0.0,0.0"
```

which is an invalid literal.

You should replace:

```
 data = cols[2:]
```

with

```
 data = cols[2:].split(',')
```